# Running migrate on postgresql db is attempting to migrate already migrated migrations

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I've recently upgraded form sqlite to postgresql for my django project.

In the past, whenever I've made a change to a model, I simply ran makemigrations and then the migrate command. No issues.

Now, with posgresql, when I make the INITIAL makemigrations/migrate, it works fine as per usual, but if I make a change to a model and then run makemigrations and then migrate, on the 'migrate' command, the system tries to apply the initial migration again and returns an error saying the table already exist (which it does).

How can I run migrate without the system trying to remigrate migrations that have already been migrated?

Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 233, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 324, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/jimmy/lib/python3.6/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "profiles_accentcolor" already exists
```

Comment: without knowing what is the main cause of this issue, a fix that could work is to delete all migration files with the except of the INITIAL one (if this migration has been applied correctly), and run `python manage.py migrate --fake`. Then run makemigrations && migrate as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i have to run python manage.py migrate --fake-initial to ignore initial migrations.